# Supporting python 2 and 3: str, bytes or alternative

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a Python2 codebase that makes extensive use of `str` to store raw binary data. I want to support both Python2 and Python3.

The `bytes` (an alis of `str`) type in Python2 and `bytes` in Python3 are completely different. They take different arguments to construct, index to different types and have different `str` and `repr`.

What's the best way of unifying the code for both Python versions, using a single type to store raw data?

Comment: Why not just stick with `str`?  It is the same between versions, right?

Comment: @zondo: no, they are not. `str` in Python 3 is roughly the same as `unicode` in 2. You can't go and store raw binary data in `str` in Python 3.

Comment: Use the `b'..'` prefix in both to define literals, and use a bridge library like `six` to handle the rest of the cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`python-future`](http://python-future.org/index.html) package has a [backport](http://python-future.org/bytes_object.html) of the Python3 bytes type.

```
>>> from builtins import bytes  # in py2, this picks up the backport
>>> b = bytes(b'ABCD')
```

This provides the Python 3 interface in *both* Python 2 and Python 3. In Python 3, it is the builtin `bytes` type. In Python 2, it is a compatibility layer on top of the `str` type.

Comment: This is the best way - allowing to just write idiomatic Python 3 code. +1 for *not* mentioning `six`, which makes the code look like crap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on what parts you want to work with bytes, I allmost allways work with bytearray's, and this is how I do it when reading from a file

```
with open(file, 'rb') as imageFile:
    f = imageFile.read()
    b = bytearray(f)
```

I took that right out of a project I am working on, and it works in both 2 and 3. Maybe something for you to look at?

Comment: That's not a very efficient way to deal with this issue. Plenty of projects manage to use `str` in 2 and `bytes` in 3.

Comment: `bytearray` is mutable, unfortunately. Immutability is important to me

Answer (score 0):

If your project small and simple use [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/).

Otherwise I suggest to have two independent codebases: one for Python 2 and one for Python 3. Initially it may sound like a lot of unnecessary work, but eventually it's actually a lot easier to maintain.

As an example of what your project may become if you decide to support both pythons in a single codebase, take a look at google's [protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/python). Lots of often counterintuitive branching all round the code, abstractions that were modified just to allow hacks. And as your project will evolve it won't get better: deadlines play against quality of the code.

With two separate codebases you will simply apply almost identical patches which isn't a lot of work compared to what is ahead of you if you want a single code base. And it will be easier to migrate to Python 3 completely once number of Python 2 users of your package drop.

Comment: `And you will likely drop Python 2 version in a year or so anyway` How can you be so sure? Personally I won't touch 3.x for many years, if ever at all and I know alot of people who feel the same. There is many reasons why one don't want to or can use Python 3.x.

Comment: I'll remove this from my answer. Wasn't intended to be offensive. If you feel to discuss why you don't need Python 2 for new project, let's do this in chat.

Comment: Separate codebases for larger projects? That's just unmaintainable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, that greatly depends on the project its code and development cycle. For something community backed it's going to be hard. In other hand, united codebase may become unmaintainable as well. Both of approaches require careful handling of each change. It's just where do you want to spend time: united codebase that's outdated and hard to debug or separate, where Python 3 version can evolve independently?

Comment: @Kentzo: projects like `requests` and Pyramid manage it just fine. Continuous integration running tests on both pythons is the key.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `requests` is one of the best community-backed python projects around :) And it doesn't really make use if asyncio, which already makes `aiohttp` better alternative on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to support Python 2.6 and newer, you can simply use `bytes` for, well, bytes. Use `b` literals to create bytes objects, such as `b'\x0a\x0b\x00'`. When working with files, make sure the mode includes a `b` (as in `open('file.bin', 'rb')`).
Beware that iteration and element access is different though. In these cases, you can write your code to use chunks. Instead of `b[0] == 0` (Python 3) or `b[0] == b'\x00'` (Python 2) write `b[0:1] == b'\x00'`. Other options is using `bytearray` (when the bytes are mutable) or helper functions.

Strings of characters should be `unicode` in Python 2, independent from Python 3 porting; otherwise the code would likely be wrong when encountering non-ASCII characters anyways. The equivalent is `str` in Python 3.
Either use `u` literals to create character strings (such as `u'Düsseldorf'`) and/or make sure to start every file with `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. Declare file encodings when necessary by starting files with `# encoding: utf-8`.
Use `io.open` to read character strings from files. For network code, fetch bytes and call [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) on them to get a character string.

If you need to support Python 2.5 or 3.2, have a look at [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) to convert literals.

Add plenty of assertions to make sure you that functions which operate on character strings don't get bytes, and vice versa. As usual, a good test suite with 100% coverage helps a lot.